# Solr is throwing an exception indicating that the collection name is missing despite sending it with the request in cloud mode

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am trying to add/delete a document to/from a collection using solrj. 
When I set a default collection on the SolrCloudClient instance, the process is done successfully. However, when I try to send the collection name with the request rather than setting the default collection, an exception is thrown:

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: No collection param specified on request and no default collection has been set.
```

I've made sure that the collection name is really sent from my code.

This is the code:

```
public void createDocument(Document document, String collectionName) throws BusinessException 
{
    SolrInputDocument solrInputDocument = new SolrInputDocument();
    //cloudSolrClient.setDefaultCollection(collectionName);

    Map<String,Object> fieldsData = document.getData();
    for( String fieldName : fieldsData.keySet() )
    {
        Object fieldValue = fieldsData.get(fieldName);
        solrInputDocument.addField(fieldName, fieldValue);
    }

    try 
    {
        System.out.println(collectionName);
        UpdateResponse documentAdditionResponse = cloudSolrClient.add(collectionName, solrInputDocument);
        if(documentAdditionResponse.getStatus() != 0)
        {
            throw new BusinessException(StaticResponseCode.SOLR_SERVER_ERROR);
        }   
        cloudSolrClient.commit();
    }
    catch(SolrException e)
    {
        throw new BusinessException(StaticResponseCode.NON_EXISTENT_COLLECTION);
    }
    catch (SolrServerException | IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new BusinessException(StaticResponseCode.SOLR_SERVER_ERROR);
    } 
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: uncomment cloudSolrClient.setDefaultCollection(collectionName);

 and use cloudSolrClient.add(solrInputDocument)

Comment: where are you creating the collection?are you sure that collection exist in your case? if not then the issue will exist. isnt it?

Comment: I know that the alternative you are offering works. I was using it in the beginning, however I am specifically asking why isn't the current code working.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that the collection exists. I can see it in the solr admin UI.

Comment: can you check the same by enabling the cloudSolrClient.setDefaultCollection(collectionName);

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `cloudSolrClient.setDefaultCollection(collectionName);`

I tested the below code and it works only when we set the default collection.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.UpdateResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrException;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;
import org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException;

public class Test {
    private static final String collectionName = "gettingstarted";

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws Exception {
        String solrZkHostPort = "localhost:2195";
        CloudSolrClient cloudSolrClient;
        List<String> zk_Hosts = Arrays.asList(solrZkHostPort.split(","));
        cloudSolrClient = new CloudSolrClient.Builder(zk_Hosts, Optional.empty()).build();
        SolrInputDocument solrInputDocument = new SolrInputDocument();
        cloudSolrClient.setDefaultCollection(collectionName);
        solrInputDocument.addField("id", "value");
        System.out.println(collectionName);
        UpdateResponse documentAdditionResponse = cloudSolrClient.add(collectionName, solrInputDocument);
        if (documentAdditionResponse.getStatus() != 0) {
            System.out.println(documentAdditionResponse.getStatus());
        }
        cloudSolrClient.commit();

    }
}
```

Please do refer the below link.

[JIRA LINK](https://issues.streamsets.com/browse/SDC-2508)

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I understood from the link is that it's not possible to add or delete a document without setting a default collection. But how does this make the issue resolved? The API now offers a broken method that doesn't behave as expected. The irony is adding the collection parameter to the API was done specifically to not set the default collection as it may lead to concurrency problems as stated in this [discussion](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7127). This issue should be re-opened IMHO.

Comment: I shared with you as I found out that. I too was of the opinion that it should work without setting up the default collection. But unfortunately it don't work without setting up the default collection. I have tried and tested. But I didn't read it anywhere that it should work without setting up default collection

Comment: It's implicitly said in the discussions on the issue to which I have linked in my last comment. I'll probably talk with the development team on the mailing list and if they approve, open a new issue on JIRA. Thanks again for your help.